# Positioning a div under other divs

Tags: css

I am currently learning how to slice a theme and i would like some help on positioning a div under other divs. For example i would like to position the divs (box1-box3) under the AdSales&Announcements divs and for them to be centered. If you notice on the fiddle the divs are not centered ad the other divs. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="AdSales">

</div>
<div id="Announcements">

</div>

<div id="Box1"></div>

<div id="Box2"></div>

<div id="Box3"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edwinakatosh/YjLCe/embedded/result/

Comment: Do these divs have specific widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the three div in a wrapper div. you need to remove the `top:` style of your div, so the wrapper can do its job

HTML

```
</div>
<div id="Announcements"></div>


<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="Box1" class="box"></div>
 <div id="Box2" class="box"></div>
 <div id="Box3" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#adSales, #Announcements{top:0}
.box{top:0; }
.wrapper{width:780px; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden}
```

`margin: 0 auto` center aligns none floated divs. `overflow: hidden` recalculates floated child divs. `width: 780px` is the total width of the wrappers child divs plus the margin

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/YjLCe/1/

Wrap a `div` around it

```
<div id="AdSales"></div>
<div id="Announcements"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="Box1"></div>
    <div id="Box2"></div>
    <div id="Box3"></div>
</div>
```

And give it a `width` and `position` it

```
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:950px;
}
```